# Azure K8s local development with Azurite and blob-csi-driver

Tags: azure, kubernetes, azure-blob-storage, azurite

We are trying to create a local development environment to emulate Azure cloud.
We found we can use [Azurite](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azurite) to emulate `Azure Blobs` locally.
However we are unable to setup [blob-csi-driver](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/blob-csi-driver) locally (via `kind` / `minikube`) so that it can use `Azurite` and mount persistent volumes into pods.

It seems `blob-csi-driver` doesn't support installation outside AKS clusters.

Is there any known option to setup this kind of development environment?

We installed `Azurite` in local K8s cluster.
We installed `blob-csi-driver` in local K8s cluster.

Azurite is running correctly.
`blob-csi-driver` does not initiate correctly.

No documentation exists on how to set it up locally and connect to `Azurite`.

Comment: Hope this reference [helps](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/blob/main/articles/aks/azure-blob-csi.md)